# Sass interpolation issue

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to access attribute with interpolation (Saas 3), but get an error.

```
    @each $icons in myPic1, myPic2 {
        [data-type=#{$icons}] span {
        background: url("/path/to/#{$buttons}.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}
    }
```

exec error: Error: Command failed: (sass):96: Invalid CSS after "...    [data-type=": expected identifier or string, was "#{$icons}] span {" (Sass::SyntaxError)

How I can access attributes in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you surround your interpolation with double quotes it will work:

```
@each $icons in myPic1, myPic2 {
  [data-type="#{$icons}"] span {
  background: url("/path/to/#{$buttons}.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}
}
```

I'm not sure why. In CSS, strings can be quoted or unquoted. As you can see in [this interesting article about quotes in strings in CSS](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values#css):

> So, a valid unquoted attribute value in CSS is any string of text that is not the empty string, consists of escaped characters and/or characters matching /[-_\u00A0-\u10FFFF]/ entirely, and doesn’t start with a digit or two hyphens or a hyphen followed by a digit.

So values you are using are correct strings without quotes.

SASS accepts as well both types of strings, quoted and unquoted. `[data-type=myPic1]` and `[data-type="myPic2"]` would be both correctly compiled. But for some reason if you use an interpolation you must quote it.

Comment: So that sounds like a bug in SASS, probably should be reported to their bugtracker :)

Comment: You are welcome :) As @sg3s says this probably should be reported to SASS team

Comment: Still breaking here
(Line 13: Invalid CSS after " @include ": expected identifier, was "[all-#{$model}-...")

Comment: @include ": expected identifier, was "[all-"#{$model}..."