# Sass interpolation doesn't work

Tags: sass

How do I escape variable in url? Seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608555/3872976) nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915999/3872976) variant do not work

```
@include image("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=")

@mixin image($base64)
    background: url(data:image/gif;base64,#{$base64}) //this is line N
    //background: url("data:image/gif;base64,#{$base64}")
```

> (Line N: Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin
>   includes, or other properties.)

I tried sass `3.4.22` and `3.5.0-rc.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that the `background` property needs to be wrapped by one of the named options.

```
@mixin image($base64)
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,#{$base64})

.class
  @include image("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=")
```

compiles to

```
.class {
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=);
}
```

with [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) and Sass v3.4.21. I had to change the order of the mixin definition and its usage to make the compilation work. I don't know if this is just a compiler thing, it might work the other way around for you.